# How to keep sending messages in websockets even when the network is down?

Tags: java, sockets, websocket, network-programming

I am using the java implementation of websockets(org.java_websocket). I am using "ifconfig l0 down" to simulate a network failure. I would like the server to keep sending messages even when the network is down and resend them(through tcp mechanism) once the network is up again. However, the java implementation has the following check in the send function

```
private void send( Collection<Framedata> frames ) {
    if( !isOpen() )
        throw new WebsocketNotConnectedException();
```

which leads to

```
an error occured
close a stream
Exception in thread "main" org.java_websocket.exceptions.WebsocketNotConnectedException
```

as soon as I simulate connectivity loss between the server and client.

Since I am not properly calling the close() function in websockets I feel the TCP mechanism should work for some time before timing out leading to websockets layer to close the connection. Am I expecting something outwordly? Is there an implementation that can help me?

Comment: I am using https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket

Comment: The issue here is not the network, it is that your code closed the socket somewhere and then continued to use it.

Comment: @EJP while, I solved this issue, could you help me with the follow up question posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40441420/getting-operation-timed-out-exception-on-socket-read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good idea to simulate network connectivity problems by `ifconfig down` because the operating system knows the interface status. The OS then may (and it does) a handle connectivity error and an interface error differently and a network application gets different error indication.

An option how to simulate a connectivity errors on a linux box is `iptables`. Let say your application uses the port 80. You can drop all communication to/from port 80 via

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 80 -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --source-port 80 -j DROP
```

The traffic drop in iptables is handled like a network outage.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Yes, that's what I resorted to do. I used the equivalent of iptables which is pfctl for mac. Now that I have done this, everything works fine for a few iterations of on and off periods but then suddenly the stream closes and connection breaks on turning up the firewall at the beginning of a off period.

Comment: I figured out the reason why the network goes down and have posted that as a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40441420/getting-operation-timed-out-exception-on-socket-read. Would be glad if you could help.

Answer (score 0):

I think your test setup here does not really do what you want. I guess what happens is that as soon as you are using `ifconfig` the operating system is smart enough to look up which sockets are bound to this interface and closes them. Thereby Java and the websocket application get notified about the closed socket and the websocket connection gets cleaned up.

You probably need another way to simulate an "unplugged" connection, in the sense of you want to see a high packet loss/latency but without an actual connection close notification.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Yes, that's what I resorted to do. I used the equivalent of iptables mentioned in the other answer which is pfctl for mac. Now that I have done this, everything works fine for a few iterations of on and off periods but then suddenly the stream closes and connection breaks on turning up the firewall at the beginning of a off period.

Comment: I figured out the reason why the network goes down and have posted that as a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40441420/getting-operation-timed-out-exception-on-socket-read. Would be glad if you could help.

Answer (score 0):

It is so late for answering to this question, but I think my answer can help another guys:
you should use

```
connectBlocking()
```

instead of

```
connect()
```

function. note that connectBlocking() , block your thread!