# Getting operation timed out exception on socket read

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp, network-programming

If I set `mSocket.setSoTimeout(1000);` I get

> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

after one second of wait on `mSocket.getInputStream().read()` which is expected.

But, if I do `mSocket.setSoTimeout(0);` I get

> java.net.SocketException: Operation timed out

after around a minute(55 seconds in most of my runs) of wait which is puzzling.

I have tried increasing sysctl tcp settings on my Mac OS El Capitan to no avail. If those settings were restricted the timeout to around a minute, I should have gotten the same read timed out exception as before. What's this operation timed out exception?

Edit: Its probably worth mentioning that I am deliberately bringing the network down using pfctl and since I am using websockets over tcp I expect the connection to not break given a large timeout and the flow to continue once I bring the network up once again.

The stack trace for both exceptions is the same ie

```
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:203)
at org.jwebsocket.kit.WebSocketProtocolAbstraction.protocolToRawPacket(WebSocketProtocolAbstraction.java:220)
```

Comment: Were there any sends in progress when you cut the network?

Comment: Yes, most likely since I am sending 1.5 msgs per sec.

Answer (score 0):

When an application calls `setSoTimeout(0)` then OS may actually wait for data forever. But there are several kinds of events that interrupts the read operation regardless the SO_TIMEOUT value.

If the OS destroys the TCP connection behind the socket then the read operation is interrupted because the TCP connection does not exist anymore and there is no chance to receive any data in future. Even if the peer sent a data later the local TCP stack would drop it (and perhaps answer TCP-RST).

The OS destroyed the TCP connection because it sent data and did not receive any ACK. So OS tried to retransmit data and it gave up after while and destroyed the connection.

Comment: As for the first argument that there are several kinds of events that could be interrupting the read, if the event that is breaking this read happens only after 54-56 seconds after the network is brought down, I suspect the number would be configurable. Any guess on what this event could be?

Comment: For the second point, "The OS destroyed the TCP connection because it sent data and did not receive any ACK." I have tried manipulating system variables using sysctl to no avail. Since others have been successful in getting much larger no response yet connection alive situation, what could I be doing wrong. 1 minute of no response seems too short a duration to break the tcp.